# Compare binary string with string VC++

Tags: visual-c++

I've a problem to compare a string from binary file with a char file, and i don't know how to solve (i'm very new in cpp).

I've this code to make a dll:

```
char text[5];

DLL_EXPORT char *LIMGcheck(char *archivo){
    FILE *origen = fopen(archivo, "r");
    if(origen){
        if(_fseeki64(origen, 0, SEEK_END)){
            fclose(origen);
            return "-1";
        }else{
            if(_fseeki64(origen, _ftelli64(origen)-16384, SEEK_SET)){
                fclose(origen);
                return "-1";
            }else{
                fread(text, sizeof(char), 4, origen);
                fclose(origen);
                //return text;
                if (strncmp(text, "LIMG", 3)){
                    return "1";
                }else{
                    //MessageBoxW(NULL, L"No tiene LIMG", L"AVISO:", MB_OK);
                    return "0";
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        return "-1";
    }
}
```

if i use "return text;" then the program return a string with "LIMG" text, but when i try to compare with string i get alwais false. I've tried with: text == "LIMG", text == LIMGText (char variable containing "LIMG"), and strncmp, and always get the same result.

Thanks in advance, maybe is a foolishness but im too new in cpp ;)

Comment: `strncmp` returns 0 if there is a match. Should the code be `(0 == strncmp(text, "LIMG", 3))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if (strncmp(text, "LIMG", 4) == 0) {
```

The `strcmp` family return an ordering; they return 0 for a match. You can't use `==` for string contents comparisons as that will compare the string pointers not the contents.

Your code is also a little hard to follow. You could consider removing all the 'else's and putting that code at the top level to make it easier to read the program flow assuming the non-error cases throughout.

For the string return you're also relying on the fifth character in your buffer always being 0. This will be true if it's a globally initialised buffer as it appears to be here, but in general if you're copying in four characters from the stream it would be safest to explicitly terminate it yourself with a zero afterwards.